# C++ Growable, Tightly Packed Data Structure with fixed indices

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I have a group of primitive data types that needed to be kept tracked by some sort of ID.

I am looking for a data structure that would let me keep them tighly packed and the collection needs to grow as needed.

The C++ std::vector would be a perfect solution, except that when it deletes an element, some indices could be changed so I could no longer reference an element by its index. I also thought about map, but it is not tightly packed.

My solution would be rewriting std::vector such as when an entry is deleted, the entry is marked as 'dirty', and when a new entry is needed, it could try to reuse 'dirty' entries and if not possible, simply grow as std::vector.

But my problem appears to be common, and I am sure someone has ran into it. Would I need to reinvent the wheel or could someone point me to another direction?

Comment: You could use a map with a pool allocator to keep them contiguous.

Comment: Could you please write an example or indicate a good reference for that?

Comment: @dutra: you can Google for examples of pools.  For example, Boost.Pool, though for some reason you don't want to use Boost, but you can always copy its files into your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `vector<boost::optional<T>>`.

To delete an item:

```
vec[val.id] = boost::none; // now this slot is empty
```

To add an item:

```
auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::none);
if (it == vec.end()) {
    val.id = vec.size(); // or however
    vec.push_back(val);
}
else {
    // this is an empty slot, overwrite it
    val.id = std::distance(vec.begin(), it);
    *it = val;
}
```

To make that more efficient, you can also keep a separate list of free indices when you do erasing - but that's just an optimization on top of the general idea.

Comment: That seems like a great answer. But could it be implemented without using boost?

Comment: @dutra If you're open to dynamic allocation, you can achieve the same effect with `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` or `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` by calling `reset()` instead of assigning to `none`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not open to dynamic allocation. I could actually use gcc 4.9 experimental::optional instead of boost.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to keep track of deleted ("dirty" in your parlance) entries is commonly done, and referred to as using a "free list."

Another idea would be to simply use the pointer (address of each datum) as the ID.

Comment: Thank you, but I think that free lists are not guaranteed to be contiguous. And I think that if I kept the memory address of an item, it could change when std::vector grows or shrinks.

Comment: You wouldn't store the values in a vector.  You would store the pointers in the vector, and use the pointer values as the IDs.  In other words, vector<Thing*>, and ID is Thing* itself, not a vector index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late the party, but what about swapping the last element with the element to be deleted and popping that element off the back of the vector? Free lists are also a good solution, but might be over engineering it depending on what you're doing.